# How can i disable apache multipart/form-data handling?

Tags: php, apache, multipartform-data

i have the following php code

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="fil">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<?php

foreach(getallheaders() as $name){
if(preg_match("~multipart/form-data~",$name)){
     die("trying to upload something?");
}
}
?>
```

the problem is php handles the file after it is processed by apache.
what i want is to take control of the multipart/form-data before it even get processed with apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set PHP's [`enable_post_data_reading`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading) directive to `Off` then use [`php://input`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input) to read the raw POST data.

Note that *php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data"* unless `enable_post_data_reading` is `Off` (the docs don't mention the last bit).

Comment: so how can i process multipart/formdata with php when it is first sent  before it is processed with apache?

Comment: Apache doesn't process it, PHP does. With the way I described you can handle the raw POST data yourself. You cannot execute any logic before the data gets to PHP if that's what you're after..